# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de la fila de una tabla dependiendo del option de un select?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

[image: esta es una imagen del formuario y las opciones del select quew se imprime en una tabla][image: imagen de la tabla donde se impreime el estaus del forulario aqui en la columna estatus]

```php
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <title>CheckHuapilla</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <link href="../estilos/estilos_c.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
      </head>
      <body >

        <!-- Example Code -->
        
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg- fixed-top" style="background-color:#002463;">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand me-auto" href="#">CheckHuapilla Mec</a>
            
            <button class="navbar-toggler pe-2" onclick="window.location.href='./perfil_mec.php'" type="button" style="left: 85%; position: absolute;"  aria-controls="offcanvasDarkNavbar">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-person-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M11 6a3 3 0 1 1-6 0 3 3 0 0 1 6 0z"/>
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 8a8 8 0 1 1 16 0A8 8 0 0 1 0 8zm8-7a7 7 0 0 0-5.468 11.37C3.242 11.226 4.805 10 8 10s4.757 1.225 5.468 2.37A7 7 0 0 0 8 1z"/>
                </svg>
            </button>
            <button class="navbar-toggler pe-2"  onclick="window.location.href='../php/cerrar.php'" type="button" style="left: 90%; position: absolute;"  aria-controls="offcanvasDarkNavbar" >
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-box-arrow-right" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 12.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-8a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-9a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0v-2A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 9.5 2h-8A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 3.5v9A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5 14h8a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-2a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v2z"/>
                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M15.854 8.354a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.708l-3-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.708.708L14.293 7.5H5.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h8.793l-2.147 2.146a.5.5 0 0 0 .708.708l3-3z"/>
                </svg>
            </button>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasDarkNavbar" aria-controls="offcanvasDarkNavbar">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            </mat-toolbar>
            <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end text-bg-" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasDarkNavbar" aria-labelledby="offcanvasDarkNavbarLabel"  style="background-color:#002463;"> 
              <div class="offcanvas-header" style="background-color: #01112e">
                <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasDarkNavbarLabel" style="color:white">OPCIONES</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="offcanvas-body">
                <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
                  <li class="d">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="citas_disponibles.php">CITAS DISPONIBLES</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="citas_realizadas.php">CITAS ELEGIDAS</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="citas_terminadas.php">HISTORIAL DE CITAS</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="calendario.php">CALENDARIO</a>
                  </li>
                  
                </ul>
                
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
     
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
    <!--Titulo de la Tabla-->
        <div fxFlex="auto" style="display: flex; justify-content: center;" >
                <h2 > Citas Elegidas</h2>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="fondotabla">
        <!--Table-->
        <table class="table table-hover table-fixed" class="table" id="tabla">
    <!--Table head-->
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="verde" class="azul" class="rojo" >
                            <th > ID</th>
                            <th > CLIENTE</th>
                            <th > VEHICULO</th>
                            <th > SERVICIO</th>
                            <th > MECANICO </th>                       
                            <th > ESTATUS</th>
                            
                        
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody >
    <?php
        include "../php/bd.php";
        $correo = $_SESSION['id_session_mec'];
        $result= mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT nombre FROM mecanico WHERE id_mec='$correo'");
                if($result->num_rows>0){
                    while($consulta= $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        $nom=$consulta['nombre'];
                        $nombre = $nom;
                    }
                }
        $buscar =" SELECT * FROM  citas WHERE nombre_mecanico='".$nombre."'  EXCEPT select * from citas where estado='Finalizado'";
        $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$buscar);
        while($filas=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
        {
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>"; echo $filas ['id']; echo "</td>";
                            echo "<td>"; echo $filas ['nombre_cliente']; echo "</td>";
                            echo "<td>"; echo $filas ['vehiculo']; echo "</td>";
                            echo "<td>"; echo $filas ['servicio']; echo "</td>";
                            echo "<td>"; echo $filas ['nombre_mecanico']; echo "</td>";
                            echo "<td>"; echo $filas ['estado']; echo "</td>";
                            ?>    

                            <div class="modal-footer rounded-0">
                                            <div class="text-end">
                                                <td><button type='button' class='btn btn-dark' style='background-color: #002463' data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#view<?php echo $filas['id'];?>">  Modificar</button></td>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        
                             <!-- Modal -->

                              <div class="modal fade" id="view<?php echo $filas['id'];?>" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                              <div class="modal-dialog">
                                  <div class="modal-content">
                                  <div class="modal-header">
                                      <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel"> ID DE LA CITA:<?php echo $filas ['id'];?></h1>               
                                      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="modal-body">   
         
                                      <p class="card-text"> El Id de cliente:<?php echo $filas ['id_cliente'];?> </p>
                                      <p class="card-text">El vehiculo elegido:<?php echo $filas ['vehiculo'];?></p> 
                                      <p class="card-text">Servicio:<?php echo $filas ['servicio'];?></p> 
                                      <p class="card-text">Comentario:<?php echo $filas ['comentario'];?></p>
                                      <p class="card-text">Fecha y hora Programada:<?php echo $filas ['start_datetime'];?></p>  
                                  </div>
                                <!--  Form -->
                                      <form action="../php/cita_modificar.php" method="POST">
                                      <div class="fadeIn second">
                                      <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel"> ID DE LA CITA:</h1>
                                          <input type="text" id="login"  name="id" value="<?php echo $filas ['id'];?>" readonly=»readonly» required >
                                      </div>  
                                      <div class="form-group">
                                              <label for="exampleSelect" for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Estado de la cita</label>
                                              <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" id="exampleSelect" name="estado" onchange="cambiarColor()">
                                                <option value="rojo" class="bg-danger text-white">Pendiente</option>
                                                <option class="bg-primary text-white">Inicializado</option>
                                                <option>En Proceso</option>
                                                <option value="verde" class="bg-success text-white">Finalizado</option>
                                              </select>
                                          </div>
                                        <div class="form-group mb-2">
                                                    <label for="description" class="control-label">Comentario</label>
                                                    <textarea rows="3" class="form-control form-control-sm rounded-0" name="comentario" id="description"  value="<?php echo $filas ['comentario'];?>" required></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group mb-2">
                                          <label for="end_datetime" class="control-label">Fecha y hora de de finalizacion</label>
                                          <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control form-control-sm rounded-0" name="end_datetime" id="end_datetime" required>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        <br>
                                          <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Modificar">
                                          
                                      </form>
                                 
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              </div>
                        <?php }
                      ?>
                    </tbody>
    <!--Table body-->
      </table>
      </div>
        <!-- End Example Code -->

      </body>
    </html>
```

Tengo un formulario hecho con Bootstrap en el cual en un `select` tengo opciones sobre el estado de una cita como *Pendiente*, *Inicializado*, *En proceso*, *Finalizado* (todos estos datos los traigo de una BD). Ahora bien, ese dato lo estoy capturando en una tabla; mi consulta es cómo asignar un color a toda la fila de la tabla dependiendo del `<option>` seleccionado.

```html
<form action="../php/cita_modificar.php" method="POST">
  <div class="fadeIn second">
  <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="staticBackdropLabel"> ID DE LA CITA:</h1>
      <input type="text" id="login"  name="id" value="<?php echo $filas ['id'];?>" readonly=»readonly» required >
  </div>  
  <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleSelect" for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Estado de la cita</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" id="exampleSelect" name="estado" onchange="cambiarColor()">
            <option value="rojo" class="bg-danger text-white">Pendiente</option>
            <option class="bg-primary text-white">Inicializado</option>
            <option>En Proceso</option>
            <option value="verde" class="bg-success text-white">Finalizado</option>
          </select>
      </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-2">
                <label for="description" class="control-label">Comentario</label>
                <textarea rows="3" class="form-control form-control-sm rounded-0" name="comentario" id="description"  value="<?php echo $filas ['comentario'];?>" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-2">
      <label for="end_datetime" class="control-label">Fecha y hora de de finalizacion</label>
      <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control form-control-sm rounded-0" name="end_datetime" id="end_datetime" required>
    </div>
    
    <br>
      <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Modificar">
      
</form>
```

Esta es la vista en la cual estoy trabajando es una aplicación web; no se alcanza a visualizar de la manera correcta pero esa es la estructura del código.

Comment: Sube una imagen para saber cómo se ve el proyecto.

Comment: Supongo que se sabe cuáles son Pendientes... dependiendo de la celda estado no?

Comment: amigo que tal  ya sybi una imagen donde se puede apreciar la tabla donde se imprime en la columa estatus la opcion del select de mi formulario

Comment: si se sabe solo que se require que se diferencie con un color para que se vea mas estetico y que se diferencie mejor el status de la tabla

Comment: No creo que cambiando el color a toda la fila quede muy estético; tal vez el fondo de la celda o simplemente el texto del estatus.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando un atributo personalizado `data-*`, en este caso `data-status` al que le asignas el valor del estado de cada fila de tu tabla, podrás filtrar luego utilizando un pequeño código Javascript:

```js
const select = document.querySelector('.select'); // el select
const rows   = document.querySelectorAll('.table tr'); // las filas de la tabla

select.addEventListener('change', (event) => { // Cuando el valor del select cambie
  rows.forEach(row => { // Recorrer cada fila
    if (row.dataset.status === event.target.value) { // Si el valor definido en el dataset (data-status="X") coincide con el valor del select (event.target.value), añade la clase que lo destaca
      row.classList.add('active-row');
    } else { // Si no coincide, borra la clase que lo destaca (por si estuviese añadida en una anterior consulta)
      row.classList.remove('active-row');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.active-row {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<select class="select">
  <option value="">Seleccionar estado</option>
  <option value="1">Estado 1</option>
  <option value="2">Estado 2</option>
  <option value="3">Estado 3</option>
</select>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Campo 1</th>
      <th>Campo 2</th>
      <th>Campo 3</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
    <tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-status="1">
      <td>Valor 1</td>
      <td>Valor 2</td>
      <td>Valor 3</td>
      <td>Estado 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-status="2">
      <td>Valor 1</td>
      <td>Valor 2</td>
      <td>Valor 3</td>
      <td>Estado 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-status="3">
      <td>Valor 1</td>
      <td>Valor 2</td>
      <td>Valor 3</td>
      <td>Estado 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Por cierto**, no declares varias veces la propiedad `class` en un mismo elemento HTML, como por ejemplo tienes en tu tabla (`<table class="clase1" class="clase2">`), simplemente añade todas las clases que quieras separadas por un espacio (`<table class="clase1 clase2">`)